# Google Place Api for getting autocomplete sugggestion for places

Tags: ios, iphone

I m using google api for autotext completion. but i m getting could not fetch places. request Denied. I have tryed with also server and browser key. but still getting same responce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create browser key, and leave the site blank.